# OpenMP tasking - way of preventing a specific thread from executing tasks?

Tags: parallel-processing, task, openmp, sse

I am creating several tasks in OpenMP, but for some reason the tasks are executed by the same thread. The code has the following pattern:

```
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(n_threads)

#pragma omp single 
while(!found){

            /.... operations with k, e, y, dist, u, step

            #pragma omp task firstprivate(k, e, y, dist, u, step)
            process(k, e, y, dist, u, step, h, out);

}
```

Is there any way of forcing the OpenMP runtime system to assign the tasks to all threads but the one that creates the task?

Thanks

Edit:

```
void process(int a[]){
    printf("Thread %d processing\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    /* Heavy Operations (used sleep to simulate them)*/
    sleep(10);
}

int main(){
    int a[10];
    int i, j;
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
        #pragma omp single
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                /* Compute a */
                for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                    a[i] += 1;
                }
                #pragma omp task firstprivate(a)
                process(a);
            }
            printf("Thread %d finished preprocessing\n", omp_get_thread_num());
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 1 finished preprocessing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't that the same question as in your other post ([Task scheduling points of OpenMP tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012199/task-scheduling-points-of-openmp-tasks/))

The answer to this one here is: no, you cannot control how the OpenMP implementation assigns the tasks to the OpenMP threads of the parallel team.

May I suggest that you post a piece of code that actually compiles?  Then it would be easier to check why the code does not behave as you think it should behave.

With the example code added by the OP, here's the behavior on my machine:

```
$> gcc -fopenmp omp.c
$> ./a.out
Thread 0 finished preprocessing
Thread 0 processing
Thread 3 processing
Thread 2 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 0 processing
Thread 3 processing
Thread 2 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 0 processing
Thread 3 processing
$> gcc --version
gcc (SUSE Linux) 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012]
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

$> icc -openmp omp.c
$> ./a.out
Thread 0 finished preprocessing
Thread 0 processing
Thread 3 processing
Thread 2 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 0 processing
Thread 3 processing
Thread 2 processing
Thread 1 processing
Thread 0 processing
Thread 3 processing
mklemm-mobl2-vm:~/tmp [0]> icc -V
Intel(R) C Intel(R) 64 Compiler XE for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 14.0.1.106 Build 20131008
Copyright (C) 1985-2013 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.
```

What compiler are you using?

Cheers,
        -michael

Comment: It's not exactly the same question. I added a simple version of the code I'm using and it's output. It should compile without problems. As you can see thread 1 is executing each task and only exits the loop when all tasks have been computed.

Comment: I'm using gcc 4.8.2. And I'm compiling it this way gcc -fopenmp -O2 test.c -o test.o.